# What happened to the User-handled column in the Exceptions dialog?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I went to Debug/Exceptions menu in VS2010 and the resulting dialog is missing User-unhandled column.  Has it been removed from VS2010?  It is present in VS2008.

VS2008
[image]

VS2010
[image]

I've tried stretching/shrinking columns, thinking, that it might just be out of the view, but nothing.  This is happening in a c# project (which is the only vs option I have installed).

Comment: It shows up for me on this version: Visual Studio 2010 Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The User-unhandled column only shows when 'Enable Just My Code (Managed Only)' is selected in Debug - Options and Settings:

[image: Enable Just My Code]

Comment: Wow, how in the world did you find this?

Comment: Same question :D